# I got the wrong output instead of what I expect, when I insert basename() function of php in html link tag

Tags: php, html, function

**Code**

```
if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Photogram/css/' . basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php") . ".css")) { ?>
    <link href="/Photogram/css/<?php basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php") ?>.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <?php } ?>
```

I try to grab basename of the file using basename function to use that file name into html link tag.

**Code**

```
if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Photogram/css/' . basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php") . ".css")) { ?>
    <link href="/Photogram/css/<?php basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php") ?>.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <?php } ?>
```

I got output like this **`<link href="/Photogram/css/.css" rel="stylesheet">`** Instead of This **`<link href="/Photogram/css/signup.css" rel="stylesheet">`**. Because My filename is signup.php So When I use basename function that Should grab the name of file(signup) to come like this  But I don't get that.

What should I do for get output like this  and tell me What happened is there.

Comment: What output are you currently getting, and what are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `basename` function does not output anything, it just returns it. You need to add an `echo` statement to get any output like this:

```php
<link href="/Photogram/css/<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php"); ?>.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thank you for considering my question and answer it, Now its working perfectly. Thanks a lot, My pleasure.

Comment: Glad to help! Most functions in PHP simply return values. So if something is not being output to HTML make sure you are actually printing it!